Legal wants terms and conditions on mobile to have agree and disagree checkboxes but without a default state. How do i go on designing it?
The last step in the registration process of our clients app requires users to agree to their terms and condition. There are two types one being mandatory and other being optional. The mandatory will have a default state of disagree/off and user need to agree/on to proceed. But for the optional part legal wants us to put the option of agree and disagree without a default state. How do i go on designing this.

I was thinking about radial buttons but will look messy on mobile.

Dropdowns also won't work.


Need some insights.

What is the reason that what you tried didn’t work? Can you add images of the current design?

not sure what do you mean. All controls have a default state, it's a boolean choice, YES/NO, ON/OFF

The Material 3 Design System uses check-boxes with an indeterminate state. I don't think I've ever seen such a thing actually in use anywhere but it definitely seems like it would meet your need.

I would suggest doing some testing just to confirm that this indeterminate state is actually understood. If you have the opportunity for usability testing I'd evaluate the check-boxes against a 3-point slider and a dropdown.
Why do you say a dropdown won't work? I would expect that to be the most universally used component for this kind of scenario.
